# Mandrill template using smtl header iwth symfony

Tags: symfony, smtp, mailchimp, mandrill, symfony-mailer

I'm using Mandrill smtp to send email with symfony and mailchimp mailer.

`"symfony/mailchimp-mailer": "6.4.*"`

I want to select the template I have in Mandrill using smtp header like Mandrill says in their documentation: https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/smtp-integration/

Code:

```
 $email = (new Email())
            ->from(new Address('contact@xxyy.com', 'TwiceFaster'))
            ->to('marc.m@cxxyy.com')
            ->subject('subject')
            ->html('test');

        $email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-Template', 'test');
        $email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-AutoText', 1);
        $email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-InlineCSS', 'true');

        $this->mailer->send($email);
```

The mail is sended but not with mandrill test template.

This is the template in mandrill:

[image]

Anyboy knows why mandrill is not sending the email using the templage?

Thank you